# Does C++ have standard queue?

Tags: c++, queue

I know that there's a standard library vector in C++. Is there a queue? An online search suggests there might be, but there's not much about it if there is one.

Edit: All right. Thanks a ton guys.

Comment: You should really find some C++ references.  There's plenty of other containers and wrappers out there!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[std::queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) (container adaptor)

Comment: +1 for the simplest answer. I always feel people should google first before asking.

Comment: Ashwin, I did google. I didn't find this site though. I'm bookmarking this one.

Comment: @Scott, You can also refer very good book by Jossutis ( Addison Wesley - C++ Standard Library, The A Tutorial and Reference)

Comment: aJ: That's probably my best bet. When I took programming, the university had switched to teaching C# as standard, so I didn't pick up on much C++. Now I want to rewrite this program of mine in C++, but it's going slowly. A book would be a great reference. I'll look into your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @Ashwin: The goal of SO is to be the *result* when people google. Saying people should try to find the answer elsewhere isn't helpful for the person asking the question *or* for SO.

Answer (score 15):

Yes there is, you could choose the underlying container easily also if you are interested:

```
#include <queue>

int main()
{
    std::queue<int> myqueue;

    myqueue.push(3);
    int x = myqueue.front();
    myqueue.pop(); // pop is void!
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there's `std::queue`. Implemented as "adaptors", on top of an existing container (since it's basically just a specialization).

Answer (score 4):

[std::priority_queue](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/priority_queue.html) and [std::queue](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/queue.html)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/queue.html

Answer (score 3):

Another good reference for the C++ standard libraries is http://www.cplusplus.com.

Specifically their reference section: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/.

Here's their page for std::queue: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue/.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you might find std::deque (double ended queue) useful, depending on what you need a queue for