# How to use built-in data structures without typing them out?

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

I wanted to write a program in c++ that implements a stack using two queues. I could type out the whole queue data structures. But is there any way where i can declare two queues q1 and q2 and use their built-in functions like enqueue,dequeue and isQueueEmpty? If so, how can i declare them and how will i know the names of their built-in functions?

Comment: Telling us the language will help a ton... also a Google will give you a ton of results on how to declare and use stacks/queues in the language you want (if they are available).

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519215/does-c-have-standard-queue

Comment: You should start by reading a book on C++. If you google "C++ tutorial" you also find resources online. C++ provides many "containers", among them queues. If you google "C++ queue" you will find reference links which list the built-in functions. How can it be that you did not try that?

Comment: You should also be more specific in your question. From other questions you asked before I see that you are implementing data structures "manually" as exercises; pointing you to `std::queue` may not be what you need if you want to use your own, hand-crafted queues. Are you perhaps asking how to avoid "typing out" all of the source code again for queues which you have hand-crafted in another project/program? Then your question aims at modular software development (and possible answers would mention libraries, header files and make files).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language you are using.If you are using C++, then you can use template feature for this.

> queues are implemented as containers adaptors, which are classes that
>   use an encapsulated object of a specific container class as its
>   underlying container, providing a specific set of member functions to
>   access its elements. Elements are pushed into the "back" of the
>   specific container and popped from its "front".

For using this feature you need to include the header file queue

```
#include <queue>
```

Then you need to create an object for the that.

```
std::queue<int> process;
```

Here value inside **<  >** specifies the type of elements in the queue. Here it is int. That is all the elements in the queue is integer type.
You can treat process as an object of the queue class, using that and dot operator you can access every member functions of queue template.

It contain the following functions (list is not complete)

1. empty() - for checking if the queue is empty or not
2. size() - for getting the size of the queue
3. front() - returns the front element
4. back() - returns the element at the back
5. push_back() - push at the back side of queue (enqueue)
6. pop_front() - pop from the front of the queue (dequeue)

You can get more details from here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/

an the below link contain an example program that illustrates the use of queue template : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/push/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.